# Oracle Forms and Reports for Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

While installing forms and reports for `Oracle 11g R2` I am facing the following error:

> Checking operating system certification status failed.

I am using `Windows 10 x64`, forms and reports version is `11.1.2.2.0`. During the web search, I found that `Windows 10` is not included in any [Certification Matrix](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25460_01/r2_fr_requirements.htm#BABEDEIH) of forms and reports. Is there any solution or I **must** switch to some other OS version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an `oraparam.ini` or `param.ini` file in the installation directory.  Within that file, there should be a `Certified Versions` section with something like:

```
Windows=4.0,5.0,5.1,5.2
```

You can try adding `,10.0*` or just `,10.0` to the end, save the file, and restart the installation and it should finish installing.  But that doesn't necessarily mean it'll work.  I never had much success getting Forms Builder to work on Windows 7 and always had to revert to XP Mode.

Comment: I found the `oraparam.ini` file in `install\win64` directory of setup, but there is not such line in that file.

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking of the 10g version.  Looks like for 11g, in Disk1\stage\prereq\Win64 there is refhost.xml file.  You can try adding another `<OPERATING_SYSTEM>` block within the `<CERTIFIED_SYSTEMS>` section for `VERSION VALUE="10.0"` or `"10.*"`  It appears the installer allows you to proceed even if the validation fails.  It would probably be safer on Windows 7 if you have it available, but you can always try and uninstall if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.. I will switch to Windows 7 now. I think you deserve an upvote :)